# Error when upgrading to Node 18.15.0 (LTS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-scripts

I just saw that Node 14 & 16 security support ends this year (https://endoflife.date/nodejs).

So I decided to upgrade to Node 18.15.0, but when running my application with `react-scripts start`, i got this error :
error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

I saw a workaround, by simply replace the start command with `react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start`. It works.

But I am not sure that this is the real solution to this issue, I don't know what --openssl-legacy-provider means, but it doesn't seems a good idea for a production app (tell me if I'm wrong).

Do you have an idea about that ?

using:
react: 17.0.2
react-scripts: 4.0.3

Comment: which OS and whats version number

Comment: @bogdanoff I'm on Windows 10. I'm currently trying to upgrade react-scripts as the other answer says, but I'm facing other issues when doing yarn install

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade to these versions

- LTS version of node
- version >5 of react-scripts
  (Uninstall and then install react-scripts)